# Single board computer with 2 GBit ethernet ports

Tags: motherboard, linux, ethernet

I am looking for a single board computer with 2x1 GBit ethernet ports, on board.

Should come with SATA and/or USB 3.

Either x86 or ARM is ok, as long as it runs Linux.

Comment: What's your budget

Comment: @AdamWykes, well, it should be cheaper than the sum of: entry-level x86 board + CPU + 2nd network card + other components

Comment: Ok. AFAIK there is no such board.

Comment: How about MIPS, is MIPS architecture OK?

Comment: @AdamWykes, yes, would be fine, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's apparently NUC style passively cooled machines meant for displays that would work.

Discourse uses [something *very* similar internally](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-scooter-computer/)

I've been toying with [buying one of these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item-img/QOTOM-Mini-PC-Q190G4-with-4-LAN-port-using-pfsense-as-small-router-firewall-fanless-PC/1000001826190.html) and it probably ticks off most of your boxes - *intel* ethernet, and 4 ports (realtek's a pain). I've run linux on a very similar platform. With the right variant, you got USB 3.0 + 2.5 inch drives, or msata.

I ended up picking up a slightly fancier model but you can get a 2 port model with a j 1800 or 1900, ram and storage for about us $150 upwards. It's fairly robust, has Intel lan adaptors (which I find better than realtek) and basic video outputs.

So yeah, they exist and for not much money.

Comment: If you can find one for cheaper than ~100, this is the way to go. It's already running pfsense

Answer (score 3):

There is the x86 [ODROID-H2](https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-h2/) SBC which comes with 2 x 1 GBit ethernet, 2 x SATA, 2 x USB 3.0 (4 USB ports in total), 1 x M.2 NVMe and more.

As of 2018-12, it's sold for $ 111.

It's based on the Intel Celeron J4105 platform (CPU is soldered) and has 2 empty DDR4 SO-DIMM slots.

When using the SATA ports you need special SATA power cables.